# using odeint to solve odes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I recently try to practice ode with python. the code below is about solving three equations that are connected with each other. that is, the first value needs to be the next equation's value and so on.

here is my code, but something wrong with odeint and print the warning 'setting an array element with a sequence.'

I have been confused for a long time, can someone see the mistake?

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

rho=1000.0  
A=10.0
g=9.8   
Gf=1.0 
fi=10.0
f0=2.0
n=101
f_=0.0
h_=1.63265306e-05 
t=np.linspace(0,60,n)
cmax=2.0

def model(z,t,v): 

    level1=z[0]
    level2=z[1]
    level3=z[2]
    v11=v[0]
    v22=v[1]
    v33=v[2]

    dlevel1_dt=(fi-f0-((cmax*v11)*((rho*g*level1/Gf)**(1/2))))/A
    f1=f_+(cmax*v1*((rho*g/Gf/h_)**2))/2*(level1-h_)

    dlevel2_dt=(f1-((cmax*v22)*((rho*g*level2/Gf)**(1/2))))/A
    f2=f_+(cmax*v2*((rho*g/Gf/h_)**2))/2*(level2-h_) 

    dlevel3_dt=(f2-((cmax*v33)*((rho*g*level3/Gf)**(1/2))))/A
    f3=f_+(cmax*v3*((rho*g/Gf/h_)**2))/2*(level3-h_) 

    dlevel_dt=[dlevel1_dt,dlevel2_dt,dlevel3_dt] 
    return dlevel_dt


level1=np.empty_like(t)
level2=np.empty_like(t)
level3=np.empty_like(t)

level0=[0,0,0]
level1[0]=level0[0]
level2[0]=level0[1]
level3[0]=level0[2]

v1=np.zeros(n)
v1[5:20]=10 
v2=np.zeros(n)
v2[30:50]=5 
v3=np.zeros(n)
v3[65:85]=2 
v=[v1,v2,v3]

for i in range(1,n): 
    tspan=[t[i-1],t[i]]    
    z=odeint(model,level0,tspan,args=(v[i],))
    level1[i]=z[1][0]
    level2[i]=z[1][1]
    level3[i]=z[1][2]   
    level0=z[1]

plt.figure()         
plt.plot(t,level1,t,level2,t,level3)
plt.show()
```

the result:

> z=odeint(model,level0,tspan,args=(v[i],))
> line 244, in odeint
> int(bool(tfirst))
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: I think that your passing an array to convert it to bool. Look for tfirst value and find where it came from? Maybe it's a single array with one element that you should convert it to a simple value.

Comment: so I need to insert another element like if else to convert it to bool?

Comment: and the for loop is aim to figure out a high level of these three tanks, so it basically needs to record different water level at same time ( 60s)

Comment: Full traceback please.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, the clip from the error message is misleading.  The problem isn't with that `int(bool`; that's just the last line of the call to `_odepack.odeint`.  Most likely `model` is returning an array, when it should be returning a scalar.

Comment: @hpaulj I accept with you. Please add full trace when error comes back.

Comment: The full traceback may help, but often we get this kind of error when `model` does not return the right kind of array.   `dlevel_dt=[dlevel1_dt,dlevel2_dt,dlevel3_dt]` creates a list of 3 elements.  I can't tell from  just reading the code, whether those elements are just numbers or not.  It should return an array that matches `y` in shape (or a list that can be made into such an array).

Comment: here is full traceback
  File "<ipython-input-65-50efeb011d64>", line 55, in <module>
    z=odeint(tank,level0,[t[i-1],t[i]],args=(v[i],))

  File "C:\Users\syuan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 244, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @hpaulj it returns an array that record the [dlevel1_dt,dlevel2_dt,dlevel3_dt]   value for each single time,so it should be change as the condition of v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-49ffe15670c0>", line 56, in <module>
    z=odeint(model,level0,tspan,args=(v[i],))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 241, in odeint
    output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. 
The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

With a sample call to `model`:

```
In [4]: res = model(level0,0,v[0])
In [5]: len(res)
Out[5]: 3
In [6]: res[0]
Out[6]: 0.8
In [7]: res[1].shape
Out[7]: (101,)
In [8]: res[2].shape
Out[8]: (101,)
```

The return is a 3 element list. First element is a scalar, but the other 2 are arrays.  `odeint` can't work with that kind of `model`.

For `dlevel1_dt`, `fi` is a number.

For `dlevel2_dt`, `f1` is derived from `v1`, which is an (101,) shape array.  Hence `dlevel2_dt` is an array.

`odeint` is trying to turn the result from `model` into a float dtype array:

```
In [13]: np.array(res, float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-703f82987b55>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array(res, float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

In sum, `model` should return a float numpy array that matches `z` in shape.

Comment: so it means that I need to change the fi and f0 to array, like np.ones(101)*10.0 and np.ones(101)*2.0 to convert to an (101,) shape array?  but once I change my code the traceback becomes 'Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-9d0a6a1072c3>", line 55, in <module>
    z=odeint(tank,level0,[t[i-1],t[i]],args=(v[i],))

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 244, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))

RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2.'

Comment: The shape `z` is (3,).  `model` must return that, not (3,101) or (101,3)...  You aren't taking the `odeint` docs seriously.

Comment: o...k...let me think about this question..

Comment: There's note in the `odeint` docs that recommends using `solve_ivp` in new code.  That's clearer about possible dimensions.

Comment: ok, I will try to use solve_ivp to figure out that, thanks lots!